# Adb device over wifi is killed off after flutter / react-native runnig commands

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, adb, adbwireless

With the device plugged on usb, i'm easily able to run my projects, whether with `react-native run-android` or `flutter run`.

But, when I try to connect to device over wifi, like this:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.xxx.x.xx
```

The device connects well and it keeps connected until I run the framework commands to run the app. I tried to wait for fifteen minutes, I runned `adb devices` and the device still was connected. After I runned `flutter run`, the device disappeared from `adb devices` list.

After I run `flutter run` or moments after the execution from React Native be more than 99.0% completed, when I run `adb devices`, it shows this:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this may be happening? Why the frameworks commands are disconnecting the device connection over wifi?